# How can i create angularjs '1' project with js extension?

Tags: angularjs

Hello there i just created my first application with angular js '1' with ng new nameofproject and then i realized that my project is not angularjs it is above with ts extension
 [image]

must i install the new project with cli command or clone it and browse it ? can someone help me thanks in advance !

Comment: Angularjs `1`??? :O

Comment: yes @RameshRajendran

Comment: You can not use `angular-cli` for `AngularJs` or `Angular 1`. It is for only `Angular 2` and above.

Comment: so i download an angularjs project and browse it ? @KaustubhKhare

Comment: Yes. Or create Javascript project and add files into it.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare i want to download it and browse it can you pass me a link?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started

Comment: i did clone it and run it but when i run it every time it does the npm install !!!